# Converting days to years in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to find the difference between 2 dates in a Pandas DataFrame this is my code:

```
raw['CALCULATED_AGE'] = ((raw.COMMENCEMENT_DATE - raw.DATE_OF_BIRTH))
```

this gives me the following output:

[Pandas Output Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIOWo.png)

I just want to convert the days to years, any easy way to do this ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Why not simply divide the days by **365** ?

Comment: This gives me (x days/365) days , which I can probably work around , but the real problem comes in when I need to convert to months

Comment: Well, converting to months would be dividing the days by 30 (approximately) or multiplying the years by 12. Of course there's a little inaccuracy which comes with this very simple approach, but maybe it's enough for your use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "relativedelta" and match it to your case:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
rdelta = relativedelta(raw.COMMENCEMENT_DATE,raw.DATE_OF_BIRTH).years
```

Full code example:

create the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
raw = pd.DataFrame({'COMMENCEMENT_DATE': ['3/10/2000', '3/11/2000', '3/12/2000'],
                   'DATE_OF_BIRTH': ['3/10/1990', '3/11/1991', '3/12/1990']})

raw['COMMENCEMENT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(raw['COMMENCEMENT_DATE'])
raw['DATE_OF_BIRTH'] = pd.to_datetime(raw['DATE_OF_BIRTH'])
```

Calc:

```
raw['CALCULATED_AGE'] = raw.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x.COMMENCEMENT_DATE, x.DATE_OF_BIRTH).years, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  COMMENCEMENT_DATE DATE_OF_BIRTH  CALCULATED_AGE
0        2000-03-10    1990-03-10              10
1        2000-03-11    1991-03-11               9
2        2000-03-12    1990-03-12              10
```

EDIT

Another solution works also for months:

```
raw['CALCULATED_AGE'] = (raw.COMMENCEMENT_DATE - raw.DATE_OF_BIRTH)/np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
raw['CALCULATED_AGE'] = raw['CALCULATED_AGE'].astype(int)
```

If you want calc for months just change 'Y' to 'M'.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and quick response! This works perfectly